# gremlin-server as docker container on Plesk

Tags: docker, plesk, tinkerpop, gremlin-server

I'm installing gremlin-server on Plesk using his docker container but I got an error reading default settings:

> WARNING: /opt/gremlin-server//opt/gremlin-server/conf/gremlin-server.yaml is unreadable
> Configuration file not found.

If I run it on my local docker I have no problems.

> docker run --rm --name test tinkerpop/gremlin-server

How can I fix the settings on Plesk?